# Slope values are not accurate in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, slope, hillshade

**Edit:** Yes, using a [DEM for a bigger area worked](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244872/qgis-slope-map-not-creating#comment383404_244872). However, now I'm getting crazy slope values, everything is around 90 degrees. It's a hillside vineyard, I don't think it's vertical.

---

I am trying to create a slope from a clipped DEM. The DEM is for a small plot of land, as you can see below. Each square is 30x30m.

[image]
[image]
The slope map is not registering values, just going from NaN to NaN.

Comment: Do you have the DEM for a bigger area? I think the algorithm needs the surrounding pixels as well.

Comment: Yes, that did it. But now I'm getting crazy slope values, everything is around 90 degrees. It's a hillside vineyard, I don't think it's vertical.

Comment: @BorisK Which is the CRS of your layer? I see that the project CRS is EPSG:4326 (i.e. a Geographic Coordinate System) and the OTF is active.

Comment: Changed it to EPSG:32718 to play nice with Google Earth. Still giving me slope values of 89...something.